# Реализация админ панели

Tags: telegram, бот, aiogram

Я создал бота в телеграме по продаже игровой валюты. И столкнулся с проблемой :как реализовать админ панель в которою будут приходить уведомления с суммой выводом игровой валюты . Я вижу данную реализацию так : обычный пользователь при нажатие на кнопку "вывод" пишет сумму вывода валюты, эта сумма отправляется ботом админу с айди и ником пользователя.
Буду благодарен если вы поможите решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так

```
ADMIN_ID = "12345567"
@dp.message_handler()
async def send_to_admin(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=ADMIN_ID, text=f"Юзер ({message.from_user_id}) с ником {message.from_user.username} желает вывести {message.text} руб.")
```

Само собой не забывайте и про фильтр для хендлера (я не писал так как это пример) и про проверку того что написал юзер. Ведь это может быть не строка цифр, что может создать проблему.
Ну и админ айди нужно где-то хранить в моем случае это глобальная переменная.

Comment: Спасибо большое! благодаря вам я всё понял